# Visualizar boleto como pdf . ZPL Zebra

Tags: java, pdf, zebra, zpl

Tengo la siguiente situación.

Estoy trabajando con el lenguaje ZPL de Zebra, tengo que realizar unas modificaciones al boleto que imprimimos. La cuestion es que no puedo hacer uso de la impresa física por lo que no puedo ver las modificaciones que realizo.

Estoy investigando la forma de ver la impresión del boleto digitalmente pero no lo he logrado, ya he instalado una impresora virtual pdf, he tratado de realizar la conversión de los archivos `.prn` `.oxps` pero no logro más que obtener lo siguiente:

```
FHOTU W 5 _ - 6[T   R[I  þ T[d @F- A 2[T   R[I   [d @F- A 2[I   [I  þ TA 2A 2C?A 2A 2A 2
FK"*"
N
R00,0
O
q672
Q1500,B30+38
S5
D11
ZT
A010,50,0,2,1,1,N,"*e-"
A090,50,0,2,1,1,N,"MARCA COMERCIAL:"
A280,50,0,3,1,1,N,"EJEMPLO DE MARCA COMERCIAL"


...................
```

Realmente no se si lo que estoy buscando sea posible. Quiero que se vea el formato del boleto en un pdf. Investigando encontré ZPL Viewer donde se coloca el código zpl y muestra el diseño final del boleto, pero el problema es que la codificación ZPL es diferente.

La codificación que utilizo es la siguiente:

```
FHOTU W 5 _ - 6[T   R[I  þ T[d @F- A 2[T   R[I   [d @F- A 2[I   [I  þ TA 2A 2CŒA 2A 2A 2
FK"*"
N
R00,0
O
q672
Q1500,B30+38
S5
D11
ZT
A010,50,0,2,1,1,N,"*e-"
A090,50,0,2,1,1,N,"MARCA COMERCIAL:"
A280,50,0,3,1,1,N,"<lbl_marca_comercial>"
............
```

¿Alguien que pueda orientarme?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la pagina de http://labelary.com/viewer.html, una vez tenga la etiqueta diseñada, exportala como ZPL o como PDF.

Suerte